# Does iTunes iPhone Restore wipe the encryption key and securely wipe your data?

Tags: iphone

I know that using `Erase all Contents and Settings` destroys the encryption key, securely wiping your data, but does simply doing the restore through iTunes then setting it up as a "New iPhone" do the same thing?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! When you ask questions here it's best to avoid referencing the title in the body of the question as it can be confusing... You might want to edit that first sentence to improve the readability!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the iPhone is returned back to non-activated state, all contents are erased with no trace. The iPhone is returned back to non-activated state during both "Erase all Contents and Settings" and iTunes set up as new iPhone.